# issues removing a git remote app

Tags: git, heroku

I am trying to remove a remote git app by doing the following:

git push heroku :master

but then I am getting the following error:

```
Invalid path
Syntax is: git@heroku.com:<app>.git where <app> is your app's name
```

why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

master is always reserved as a special branch.

```
git checkout --orphan master2
# replacement project
git add -A
git commit -m "start of other project"
git push -f master2:master
```

That should replace your old project.

Answer (score 0):

This looks to me like your .git/config is a bit screwy.

Ensure that the syntax for the heroku remote matches the following:

```
git@heroku.com:appname.git
```